# Counting with range and terms in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm attempting to do a `count` query such that I return the number of unsuccessful attempts to log into my system within the last 10 minutes. I created this query:

```
{
  "term": {
    "success":false
  },
  "range": {
    "_timestamp": {
      "gt": "now-10m"
    }
  }
}
```

However, this returns all of the unsuccessful attempts for any time, disregarding the `range` filter in my query. Am I structuring this query correctly? The query works when I do a `search` with terms and ranges.

In other words, the output of the above query and `curl -XGET localhost:9200/application/_count` is the same (I have only tested unsuccessful attempts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the search_type parameter instead of using the countAPI. This is actually preferred:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/application/_search&search_type=count -d'{
    query:....
}'
```

Documentation:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/search-type/

Answer (score 0):

The `range` is a filter, so I think you have to create a `filtered` query to take it correctly into account :

```
{
  "filtered": {
    "query": {
      "term": {
        "success":false
      },
    },
    "filter: {
      "range": {
        "_timestamp": {
          "gt": "now-10m"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work and still gives me output of `count: 4`, the same as a `GET` request to `localhost:9200/application/_count`

Comment: I think I get it. The `range` is only a filter. You have to use a filtered query. I will update my answer.

Comment: Same issue... :( I was able to successfully get the correct results during a `search` query with my parameters, but `count` will not accept them and only goes after term.